# How to put Form in TabPanel with ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to put a form in a tabPanel. I do this:

Form:

```
var zem = new Ext.FormPanel({
    title: 'Общие сведения',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    items: [{
        xtype:'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Местоположение',
        name: 'address',
        anchor:'80%'
    },{
        layout:'column',
        items:[{
            columnWidth:.5,
            layout: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype:'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Кадастровый номер',
                name: 'cadastr',
                anchor:'80%'
            }]
        },{
            columnWidth:.5,
            layout: 'form',
            items: []
        }]
    }]
});
```

Panel:

```
var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
    xtype:'tabpanel',
    activeTab: 0,
    autoScroll: false,
    layoutOnTabChange: true,
    items: [zem]
});
```

And I get this:

[image]

I am getting an empty tab. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not possible put FormPanel in TabPanel which be in another FormPanel. I gonna do like in the [example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/form/dynamic.html) .

Comment: Example link is broken